# Search Bar with multiple input and multiple filter rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, search, rails-geocoder

My question is how can i in multi-input search bar filter my announcements with multiple filter ?

I would like to index just the announcements who respects my conditions.

Now i just search with geolocalisation and references.

Informations :

- I used a PostgreSQL database with ActiveRecord
- Coding Language : Ruby On Rails
- Type of project : Web Site For Estate
- Search Gem : Pg Search
- Geolocalisation Gem : Geocoder

***Annoucements_Controller.rb***

```
def index
    if params[:search]
    @annoucements = Annoucement.all if params[:search][:search_by_city] == "" && params[:search][:search_by_reference] == ""
    @annoucements = Annoucement.near(params[:search][:search_by_city], params[:search][:distance], units: :km) if params[:search][:search_by_city] != ""
    @annoucements = Annoucement.search_by_city_and_reference(params[:search][:search_by_reference]) if params[:search][:search_by_reference] != ""
    else
    @annoucements = Annoucement.all
    end
  end
```

***home.html.erb***

```
  <%= simple_form_for :search, url: annoucements_path, method: :get  do |form|%>
        <%= form.input :search_by_status,label: false , collection: ['A vendre', 'A louer'], selected: "A vendre"%>
        <%= form.input :search_by_city, as: :string, label: false , placeholder: 'Ville'%>
        <%= form.input :search_by_reference, as: :string, label: false , placeholder: 'Reference'%>
        <%= form.input :distance, as: :hidden, input_html: {value: 10}%>
        <%= form.submit "Rechercher", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <% end %>
```

***annoucement.rb***

```
geocoded_by :address
  after_validation :geocode, if: :address_changed?

  include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :search_by_city_and_reference, against: {:city => 'A', :reference => 'B'}
```

My objectif it's to filter all the data present in this form :
***index.html.erb***

```
<%= simple_form_for :search, url: annoucements_path, method: :get  do |form|%>
       <%= form.input :search_by_status,label: false , collection: ['A vendre', 'A louer'], selected: "Achat"%>
       <%= form.input :search_by_city, as: :string, label: false , placeholder: 'Ville'%>
       <%= form.input :search_by_reference, as: :string, label: false , placeholder: 'Reference'%>
       <%= form.input :distance, label: "Périmètre de recherche (en Km)", input_html: {value: 10}, collection: 1..50%>
       <%= form.input :price, as: :integer, label: false , placeholder: 'Prix'%>
       <%= form.input :number_of_bedroom, as: :integer, label: "Nombre de chambre", placeholder: 'Nombre de chambre'%>
       <%= form.input :number_of_bathroom, as: :integer, label: 'Nombre de salle de bain',placeholder: 'Nombre de salle de bain'%>
       <%= form.input :size, label: 'Taille du bien (m2)', as: :integer, placeholder: 'Taille du bien (m2)'%>
       <%= form.input :field_size, as: :integer, label: 'Taille de terrain (m2)', placeholder: 'Taille de terrain (m2)'%>
       <%= form.input :balcony, as: :boolean, placeholder: 'Balcon'%>
       <%= form.input :garage, as: :boolean, placeholder: 'Garage'%>
       <%= form.input :furnished, as: :boolean, placeholder: 'Meublé'%>
       <%= form.submit "Rechercher", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<%end%>
```

Thank you,
Bye